# Not Equal to query for SQL server

Tags: sql

I was trying to execute a query which gets me all the info from Merchant table where PackageID is not equal to 21 or 22 or 23..

Select * from Merchant where PackageID NOT '22' Union Select * from Merchant where PackageID Not '21'

Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks all!! It was so quick :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use PackageID NOT IN (21, 22, 23..)

```
 Select * from Merchant 
 where PackageID NOT IN (21, 22, 23)
```

Comment: When the result in null, shows up as `(null)`, then `NOT IN` doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to also include null results?

Comment: @Matthew Doucette where ISNULL(PackageID,0) NOT IN (21, 22, 23, 0)

Comment: ah thanks. null never results in a `true` result. this explains my problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Merchant WHERE Packageid NOT IN ('21', '22', '23')
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM Merchant
WHERE PackageID NOT IN ('21','22','23')

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Merchant where PackageID NOT IN ('21', '22', '23')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NOT IN`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php) clause for this:

```
select * 
from Merchant 
where PackageID not in ('21','22')
```